# How to speed up this code

Tags: vb.net, optimization

I've been working on a memory editor for a while now. One of the key aspects of it is look through the memory for values that match a search term. This is however extremely slow. Here's the code:

```
For i = 0 To 1318706384 - 4 Step 4

    For j = 0 To 3
        temparry(j) = alldata(i + j)
    Next

    tempint = BitConverter.ToSingle(temparry, 0)

    If tempint + 0.01 > xposs AndAlso tempint - 0.01 < xposs Then
        ReDim Preserve xpos(xpos.GetLength(0))
        xpos(xpos.GetLength(0) - 1) = i

    End If

    If InStrRev(i.ToString, "000000") > 0 Then
        Label1.Text = i / 1318706384 * 100
        Me.Update()
    End If
Next
```

Any advice on how to speed it up would be great! The xpos array is only redim'ed about 50 times so that does't make up a large amount of the time (it's a small array). Thanks!

Comment: Wow I haven't even heard of codereview. Although looking at codereviews definition it seems like this is still the right place for my question as I'm asking for specific help on how to change something. Not reviewing my code entirely. Do you agree?

Comment: You could definitely get a huge improvement by using pointers and `unsafe` code, but unfortunately it's not possible in VB.NET.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I removed my close vote and the comment.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Ok thanks! Unfortunately VB.net is the only language I really know.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible in C# but I learned C# form vb.net in really 1 or 2 days it is the same logic. Do not stop if this is the problem. If all your code is in vb, no problem just make a dll in c# and import this sub

Comment: @bto.rdz: Really? The whole C3 language in 1 or 2 days? I can't even find a link anywhere to C3 - is that an early version of C? Is there a C3.1 yet? ;-)

Comment: I said C#, sorry I edited my previous comment. C# 5.0

Comment: Don't ReDim your array over and over again. Set it to a size larger than you need, and use a counter to keep track of how many of the elements you actually use, and then ReDim down to that size after your loop finishes. The memory allocations for each ReDim take time.

Comment: @bto.rdz: You did see the :-), didn't you? It was a joke. :-D

Comment: lol I googled it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization

Comment: @KenWhite as I said in the question the redim-ing of the array is not the issue. This code is run over 329 million times and the array is only redimm-ed about 50 times.

Comment: I've already benchmarked! Thanks for the suggestion though. I suppose I should implement this for distribution. Good practise and what not

Comment: Which is the bottleneck on your code?

Comment: Have you tried profiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that should help with the speed is, instead of creating a temporary array just pass the start index to `BitConverter.ToSingle`.

```
'For j = 0 To 3
    'temparry(j) = alldata(i + j)
'Next

tempint = BitConverter.ToSingle(alldata, i)
```

if the 0's your searching for in that last bit are at the end then  the modulus operator, `Mod`, should probably work better than casting i to a string and searching the string

```
If i Mod Math.Pow(10,5) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Will this only take 4 bytes of the alldata array?

Comment: yes it does [BitConverter.ToSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I added another thought for you.

Comment: I'm implemented both suggestions, it's now about 10 times fast! Thanks a lot! :D